# expected primary-expression before 'data'

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to block the x and y data from dropping under zero.

Nothing has come to my mind.

```cpp
void serialEvent() {
  serialData = Serial.readString();
  serX.write(parseDataX(serialData));
  serY.write(parseDataY(serialData));
}

int parseDataX(String data) {
  data.remove(data.indexOf("Y"));
  data.remove(data.indexOf("X"), 1);
  return data.toInt();
}

void loop(){
  if (parseDataX < 0){
    parseDataX(String data) = int(0);
  }
}

int parseDataY(String data) {
  data.remove(0, data.indexOf("Y") + 1);
  return data.toInt();
}
```

Just want to stop x and y when they drop below zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the check inside `serialEvent()`:

```cpp
void serialEvent() {

  serialData = Serial.readString();

  int x = parseDataX(serialData);
  if(x < 0)
    x = 0;

  int y = parseDataY(serialData);
  if(y < 0)
    y = 0;

  serX.write(x);
  serY.write(y);
}
```

Or you could return `0` from the parsefunctions.